# Toast notifications in Jhipster (v4) with Angular2

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm configuring my notificaitons on a jhipster app (v4, with version of ng-jhipster : 0.1.8).

Normal built in notifications work fine, but I would like to have toast notifications. There are many different packages, likes [angular2-notifications](https://jaspero.co/resources/projects/ng-notifications), but exploring the Jhipster code I find the alertService constructor allows us to set Toast as true or false.

Yet my notifications don't show up now, and I can't find documentation explaining this feature. Do you know more about it? Has anyone done this?

Thank you for your time! :)

UPDATE:
I found this in *shared-common.module.ts*:

```
 export function alertServiceProvider(sanitizer: Sanitizer, translateService: TranslateService) {
        // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
        let isToast = true;
        return new AlertService(sanitizer, isToast, translateService);
    }
```

It does not look likea proper toast yet, so I will keep looking and keep you guys informed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem setting "isToast" as true and changing the CSS of Alerts.

Here the code:

```
.alert {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px !important ;
    top: 20px !important ;    
}
```